# Three.js Tubes not long enough

Tags: typescript, three.js

I want to connect vertices with line segments. This is what i got with simple lines. It works fine.

```
let line2 = (from : Vector3, to : Vector3) : THREE.Line => {

    var lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var positions = new Float32Array( 3 * 2 );  

    positions[0]=to.x;
    positions[1]=to.y;
    positions[2]=to.z; 

    positions[3]=from.x;
    positions[4]=from.y;
    positions[5]=from.z; 

    lineGeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

    let lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0f35ff } ); 

    let line = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial); 

    return line;

};
```

[image: Lines ends closed in points as expected]

But when i switch to tubes problem occur, length become shorter.

[image]

Code for tubes, positions data is the same.

```
let tube = (from : Vector3, to : Vector3) : THREE.Mesh => {

    let path = new THREE.LineCurve3(to, from);  

    let tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( path, 32, 0.05, 8, true);

    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x3212ac});  

    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tubeGeometry, material);

    return mesh;

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit seems to be the "closing" of the tube ends, if you enable this THREE no longer generates the final segment of the cylinder (try passing `false` as the final parameter to the TubeGeometry constructor to see the difference).

As a quickfix, in the `generateBufferData()` method of the `TubeBufferGeometry` source, try something like

```
//generateSegment((closed === false) ? tubularSegments : 0);
generateSegment(tubularSegments);
if (closed === true)
    generateSegment(0);
```